# require method not working in React for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, require

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/animation.css';

const Animation = ({ name, gif, description, link }) => {
    return (
        <div className="block">
            <div className="naslov-link">
                <h3>{name}</h3>
                <span className="animation-link-header">
                    <a href={link} className="animation-link">Visit</a>
                </span>
            </div>  
            <img src={require(gif)} alt={name}/>
            <p>{description}</p>      
        </div>
    );
}

export default Animation;
```

gif is location of the image that is taken from database, I tried logging it and it works, but image
can't be loaded. I get:

Error: Cannot find module '../images/placeholder.jfif'

on line :

```
<img src={require(gif)} alt={name}/>
```

also tried

```
<img src={gif} alt={name}/>
```

Then I don't get error but image can't be loaded, I get the alt text

Comment: Check your current location and the relative path from DB, also do not store image path in DB rather upload it into a CDN and  get a public URL

Comment: does `src={gif}` works?

Comment: @PunitMakwana, no it doesn't work either

Comment: @BiswaBhusan path is good, I tried using it manually, then it works, but when it is stored in variable it doesn;t work

Comment: @AndrijaGajic your path is not "good" - if you type in the string manually and it works, then whatever the value of the `gif` prop is must not be the same as the manual path you're typing in. Fix it.

Comment: @Adam I get this when I log gif:  ../images/placeholder.jfif and it doesn't work, but when I type in manually  "../images/placeholder.jfif" it works